# Crystal Report vertical Textbox alighment

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I am currently creating the crystal report and would like to make the textbox in the page headers to be bottom placesand grow on upper rows. but now I cannot and only click the can grow properties, what else I can proceed in order to achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: Crystal report still does not included any functionality to set text alignment vertically. read this thread on SAP Community. http://scn.sap.com/thread/3417198